# difficulty with bootstrap css positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a really simple problem with css but the solution is not coming to me. It's about positioning elements in a grid, I want the grid elements to look like [this](http://imgur.com/MReJdFn), but instead they are coming out to look like [this](http://imgur.com/s3kSMPZ). I tried putting one tag inside the other and then attempting to remove the box model from it (margin and padding) but the div is offset. I've tried nesting both inside a div tag but that doesn't work either.

I attempted to do a jsfiddle but it's not loading correctly. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kj0bohm/) . required random code below of the html.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:85.3px">empty top</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:85.3px">logo</div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="col-md-7" style="height:40px">head text
        <div class="col-md-7" style="margin-left:0px;padding-left:0px;margin-top:40px;box-sizing:border-box;">nav</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Just fyi the bootstrap col-md-1 through col-md-12 are bootstraps grid positioning system. I think they have to add up to 12 to form a single line. [Here](http://pastebin.com/DmkDrPZW) is the bootstrap html i am using. 
 and the [grid css](http://pastebin.com/xq1V8uL8)  . and [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsfiddle is not displaying correctly because the default iframe size is too small, but you can change the width to view the page in a manner consistent with your problem.  Your problem is that you have a `div` nested inside another `div` by mistake.  Try the following instead:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="height:85.3px">empty top</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="height:85.3px">logo</div>
        <div class="col-md-8" style="height:45.3px">head text</div>
        <div class="col-md-8" style="height:40px;">nav</div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Comment: thanks! The div nested inside the other was me trying to figure out how to make it work. My only problem is that I have no understanding of why your solution works, how is the third div appearing underneath the 2nd div? I don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: In bootstrap the "col-md-x" classes all have a `float: left` style.  This causes the divs to stack horizontally until the edge of the page, then cascade down and to the left.  "Empty top" obviously takes up the whole page, which causes "logo" to bump down to the next area in which it can fit horizontally.  "Head text" fits between "logo" and the end of the page.  "Nav" cannot fit between "head text" and the end of the page, so it cascades down to the next available space.  Does that help?